# Can't mass-assign protected attributes: first_name, last_name, email, password, password_confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, attr, mass-assignment

I have `user` model with use of [devise gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), I dont have `attr_accessible` for any fields still I get the error:

> Can't mass-assign protected attributes

My `User` class as below

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, 
         :token_authenticatable  #, :validatable
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also have the same problem, maybe devise does something with `attr_accessible`. You need to set up `attr_accessible` in your model to make it work.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
:recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :token_authenticatable #, :validatable`

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
end
```

You can checkout these railscasts episodes.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise

http://railscasts.com/episodes/210-customizing-devise

Comment: I have added the line in the user model
`attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :first_name, :last_name`
Still i get the same error, 
but once i do false to `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes` in application.rb and by removing attr_accessible line in the user model then only it works

Comment: Check the error again. Does the error message has changed or the same? Maybe you have more attributes when doing mass-assignment.

Comment: I have below list of params when it submits form
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 `"authenticity_token"=>"Q4R+ytentT8YlYMslUfkY9Ehq43+9xKvc8cF4vGsJNM=",
 "user"=>{"first_name"=>"",
 "last_name"=>"",
 "email"=>"",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"},
 "_save"=>"Save"}`

And my attr_accessible in user model as `attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :first_name, :last_name,`

Comment: Yes gets the same issue when i tried on the console, but now if i set attr_protected instead of attr_accessible then it works for me

Answer (score 2):

If I have put the `attr_protected` instead of the `attr_accessible` then it works for me.
FYI, I am using Rails 3.2.3 with Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: It's an answer although it doesnt explain anything. let me do it for you: In rails 3+ mass assignment is automaticly protected (config in environment.rb files) therefor you must either whitelist wanted properties or blacklist unwanted properties by using attr_protected OR attr_accessible there you go :)

Answer (score 0):

Since Rails 3.2.3, `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes` in `config/application.rb` is  `true` by default. You must manually set `attr_accessible` for attributes that needs to be mass-assignable (or you can set `whitelist_attributes` to `false` to disable this behavior).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. it works if i set to `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false`
But if i set `attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :first_name, :last_name` then it throws same error

Answer (score 0):

I set only attr_accessible :name, :password, :password_confirmation and it is working,
without set config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false in config\application.rb
Only check for correct names of vars from _form.html.erb in the attr_accessible.